# Is unprofessional to announce on my website that I'm looking for a job?

Tags: job-search

It's not exactly a secret to anybody the exact day when my current position ends. The exact duration is even set by law, and my boss is as well aware of it as anybody. So, my question is, are there any reasons to not put that detail on my website or social network profiles?

Some could argue that by making it so public I'm disclosing that I haven't been able to find anything until now. The truth is that I haven't sent any applications anywhere yet. Also, full disclosure, any potential employer would have to go through some legal hurdles to get me a work permit, so my chances are lower than that of the average Joe. I have skills that I think are in demand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the purpose of the website is to find employment, it's highly professional. Good things to put on the website if you're a developer are working examples of stuff you do, such as JavaScript demos, in particular.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the website is fully professional. And the javascript demos are coming.

Answer (score 2):

You need a job. There are many ways to find a job. One way is to use your professional and social networks to help you find a job. If they don't know you need a job they wont know to make suggestions.

Yes you need to start applying, and searching, but those networks you have established  can help you. Some of the professional contacts you have may be the key to opening the door in their company. It also may come from social contacts.

Your professional web site may also play a role in potential employers evaluating you, so you need to make sure that the social only contacts know about your website.

As part of the job search you should also spend time trying to expand your networks.

Comment: Thanks @mhoran_psprep. You have a good point with the social network.